# Ordinary Differential Equations 3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am struggling to show that every periodic orbit $\Gamma$ of a smooth flow on $\mathbb{R}^2$ surrounds a rest point of the flow.

Is there any way to use Zorn's Lemma and Poincare-Bendixson Theorem to establish the result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to establish the result. Assume the contrary, that inside some closed curve there is no rest point. Then, by the Poincare-Bendixson theory for some point inside this curve the $\alpha$ and $\omega$ limit sets have to be different closed curves. This means that inside any closed curve has to be another closed curve. After this you should be able reach a contradiction.

*Added:* Here is the full argument. Let $L_0$ be the initial closed curve. Denote the area bounded by $L_0$ as $D$. Define in $\overline{D}$ function $F(M)$ such that if $M$ belongs to some closed curve, then $F(M)$ is the area inside this curve, if $M$ does not lie on any curve, then $F(M)$ equals to the area inside $L_0$. $F(M)$, due to assumption that inside $L_0$ there are no rest points, is defined everywhere in $D$. Obviously $0<F(M)<I_0$, and $F(M)$ has an infinum in $D$, which I denote $m\geq 0$. Either there is a point $M$ such that $F(M)=m$ or there is no such point. There exists a sequence of points $M_n$ such that $F(M_n)\to m$, assume that $M_n\to\tilde{M}$. In both cases the infinum of $F(M)$ in a neighborhood of $\tilde{M}$ is $m$. Consider a curve $L$ passing through $\tilde{M}$. This curve cannot be not closed (we would not have $m$ then, because there would be a neighborhood such all the curves are non closed, hence infinum $F(M)$ cannot be $m$ here). Then $L$ is closed. Let $L_1$ be a closed curve inside $L$ and $L_2$ is a closed curve inside $L_1$. Denote $I_1$ and $I_2$ the areas that are inside $L_1$ and $L_2$. We must have $I_1>I_2$. On the other hand, we also must have $F(\tilde{M})\geq I_1>I_2$, but this contradicts the fact that $m$ is an infinum, hence there is a rest point inside $L_0$.